# How to make Xcode segues nonreversible?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, view, storyboard

XCode now has this feature where when you make a segue on the storyboard, the segue becomes reversible. This means you can go back to the previous view by sliding from the top down. Currently, I am using a Show Detail (e.g. Replace) segue in the storyboard. It looks like this:

How do I disable this feature? I just want the new view to completely show without being able to go back.

Comment: If you found the solution, add an answer and be clear about what you did. This is so other people can benefit from your experience. Otherwise, it's just you wanting to get information from others without giving back.

Answer (score 0):

Use `modalPresentationStyle` property of UIViewController.

```
let vc = UIViewController()
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: This isn't working for me. Do I change UIViewController() to the name of my next ViewController? Is this all programmatic or do I have to do something in the storyboard? Do I do this in the first view controller or the second one (that I am transitioning to)?

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it in prepare for segue:

```
segue.destination.modalPresnetationStyle = .fullscreen
```

Comment: I tried this where I needed to perform the segue: 

let mySegue = UIStoryboardSegue(identifier: "potholeSegue", source: self, destination: PotholeViewController())
            mySegue.destination.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
            mySegue.perform()

This did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Select the destination view in IB. Then show its Attributes Inspector. In Presentation, select full screen instead of automatic.

Answer (score 0):

## Storyboard

You can achieve this directly from the storyboard with selecting the destination controller and set the `presentation` style from **attributes inspector** pan:

[image: Storyboard]

## Code

Also you can do this in code:

```
let destination = segue.destination // or directly PotholeViewController() 
destination.modalPresnetationStyle = .fullscreen
```